# Develop WebAPI using mono

Tags: mono, asp.net-core, monodevelop

Is there any guide or documentation to build a REST API using Mono console or MonoDevelop. I tried to create MVC application in MonoDevelop however couldn't find App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs or relevant files by which I can define routes and other settings which I usually do in Visual studio based application.

Comment: I've created a sample project at https://github.com/sashoalm/HelloWebApi which creates an endpoint at http://localhost:8080/api/HelloWebApi that returns a string with "hello, world". I've tested it on Linux with MonoDevelop 5.10.

Comment: Thank you so much @sashoalm .I spent the whole day in finding the example for Web API using Monodevelop and you saved my day. Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is there is no template in MD for this, however it's very easy to get going:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Project (the bottom project in the MD ASP.NET project templates).
2. Use NuGet to add ASP.NET Web API 2.2.
3. Add an App_Start folder manually, and a WebApiConfig.cs with your routes etc.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyWebApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

4. Add WebApiConfig configuration into the Global.asax.cs

For example:

```
protected void Application_Start (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

5. Then start adding your models and controllers etc. as usual.

Hope this help, M.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this: now MD does have a template for it. It does pretty much what muszeo did above.

Answer (score 4):

I followed the instructions given in @muszeo's answer and it worked.

I've created a sample project at https://github.com/sashoalm/HelloWebApi. It defines a single controller called `HelloWebApiController`, which creates an endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/api/HelloWebApi` that returns a string with "hello, world".

I've tested it on Linux with MonoDevelop 5.10.

You can clone it using `git clone https://github.com/sashoalm/HelloWebApi.git`

Answer (score 1):

The best place to start is the official ASP.NET documentation: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

I haven't used MonoDevelop but I don't think it supports dnx based apps. To generate the app skeleton you can use yo https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet

Then you can use VS Code to edit your code https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I got something [Here](http://blog.opinionatedapps.com/webapi-aspnet-vnext-mono-via-docker-on-ubuntu-linux-part-1/) which uses mono. Not sure dnx.
Basically I am comparing Visual Studio templates Vs MonoDevelop template as like apple to apple. Which I supposed to be not. 

**May be I am walking on the way without proper defined route**.

Need to define proper path:
1. What goes together (MonoDevelop stand alone OR MonoDevelop with dnx or something else)
2. Should I use command line to develop .NET open source project or any tool as VS code 
3. How can I run MVC/Web API application on Ubuntu.

Comment: _**Looking for help as per above mentioned comments.**_